# Unreadable Characters in a String

Tags: php, text, fopen, strlen

This is the code which gets a text and do a process on every line:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('text.txt' , 'r');
$i = 0;
while($line = fgets($f)){
    if($i == 1){
        $first_line = $line;
    }elseif($i == 2){
        $second_line= $line;
    }elseif($i == 3){
        $third_line = $line;
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

The `text.txt` contains:

```
3
ABC
aBD
```

When I run below code, it gives me a strange output which is:

```
echo strlen($second_line);
```

`$second_line` should be `ABC` but the returned output is this:

```
5
```

Also `urlencode($second_line)` shows:

```
ABC%0D%0A
```

one of these 5 characters is `"\n"` that goes to next line

The main question is, what is the another one hidden character?

Comment: Try `echo urlencode($k);` and show the result

Comment: it's in widows and i run the code via wamp @NigelRen

Comment: Windows uses `"\r\n"` for line endings.

Comment: so if i use `str_replace("\r\n" , "",$line)` it will be ok yup?

Comment: You could just use the general `$line = trim($line);` to ensure any extra spaces/line endings are removed.

Comment: thank you very very much it was so much helpful Dear @NigelRen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Windows uses `\r\n` as the line termination, this will add an extra 2 chars to each string.  Linux only uses `\r` so this is just 1 extra.

To provide a generic solution, it would be better to use

```
$line = trim($line);
```

which will remove any line termination characters.  It will also remove leading and trailing spaces.